# Android 'drawable' folders selection issue

Tags: android

I am currently building an Android application (a game). I have created ldpi, mdpi and hdpi of all of the images (the dimensions of all of these images have been appropriately calculated).

When I test the game on my Samsung S3, the value of the below code is 2.0.

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

This is correct, and all images used in the application are automatically selected from the drawable-hdpi folder.

However, when I test the application on my Google Nexus One, the above code evaluates to 1.5 (correctly), and yet images from the drawable-hdpi folder are still automatically selected.

For reference, I am loading the bitmaps in this manner:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmpFactoryOptions.inScaled = false;
Bitmap exampleBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gamePanel.getResources(), R.drawable.example, bmpFactoryOptions);
```

*EDIT: Removing the second line still does not fix the issue.*

Am I doing something wrong? If so, what? Alternatively, is there a workaround?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Samsung Galaxy SIII is an XHDPI device.

The Nexus One is a HDPI device.

Reference:

http://blog.blundellapps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Therefore, because you don't have XHDPI resources, it uses the next closest for the SIII (hdpi).

Comment: Thanks for concisely clearing up the issue. The reference has provided me with a significant amount of extra detail. The image at the bottom of the article was especially useful. I will give you 'Best answer' since the article referenced will probably be the most applicable to general issues relating to pixel densities (for people searching for answers in the future).

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that the S3 (2.0 density) is xhdpi, whereas the Nexus One (1.5 density) is hdpi. 1.0 is the reference density (mdpi). What's most likely happening is that the S3 is falling back to the hdpi folder since you've not provided xhdpi resources, and the Nexus One is correctly pulling from the hdpi folder.

Comment: Aha! I did not realise that 2.0 linked to xhdpi (I foolishly assumed that 1.0 linked to ldpi). Thank you very much for your timely response, you have saved me much frustration.

Comment: @WillManson 1.0 means a ratio of 1 and MDPI is the 'baseline' resolution. Here's an image to explain: http://developer.android.com/images/screens_support/screens-densities.png